# Show parent.parent combobox from one2many model Odoo

Tags: view, model, odoo, odoo-15

for example I have three model :

```py
class state(models.Model):
_name = 'odoo_school.state'
_description = 'State Reference'

     name = fields.Char(String='Name')
     district_id = fields.One2many('odoo_school.district', 'state_id', string='District')

class district(models.Model):
_name = 'odoo_school.district'
_description = 'District Reference'

     name = fields.Char(String='Name')
     state_id = fields.Many2one('odoo_school.state', string='State')
     subdistrict_id = fields.One2many('odoo_school.subdistrict', 'district_id', string='SubDistrict')

class subdistrict(models.Model):
_name = 'odoo_school.subdistrict'
_description = 'Subdistrict Reference'

     name = fields.Char(String='Name')
     district_id = fields.Many2one('odoo_school.district', string='DIstrict')
```

I want to place state combobox in form view subdistrict , so when I choose state, onchange it will change combobox district for selected state. How I do that in Odoo ?

state combobox shown in subdistrict view and change combobox district for selected state